# issue about checking the point Inside a polygon - javascript

Tags: javascript, polygon

I have two almoust the same the polygons (sets of geo points)
where the first is

```
[ [ 58.854228973, 28.761459351 ],
  [ 71.395217896, 59.678779602 ],
  [ 76.377861023, 118.789276123 ],
  [ 65.617507935, -172.369491577 ],
  [ 52.024528503, 132.607208252 ],
  [ 59.828151703, 86.781745911 ],
  [ 56.686351776, 83.388923645 ],
  [ 54.459960938, 49.641719818 ],
  [ 51.9220047, 43.614974976 ],
  [ 53.87097168, 33.840515137 ] ]
```

and the second:

```
[ [ 58.854228973, 28.761459351 ],
  [ 71.395217896, 59.678779602 ],
  [ 76.377861023, 118.789276123 ],
  [ 65.617507935, -172.369491577 ],
  [ 52.159870148, 132.607208252 ],
  [ 59.828151703, 86.781745911 ],
  [ 56.686351776, 83.388923645 ],
  [ 54.459960938, 49.641719818 ],
  [ 51.9220047, 43.614974976 ],
  [ 53.87097168, 33.840515137 ] ]
```

The only diff between sets is the first has lattitude = 52.024528503 and the secod = 52.159870148

I've tried to check if point [ 55.830902099609375, 49.066734313964844 ] is included in each polygon
by using the next libs:

https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib/

https://github.com/mikolalysenko/robust-point-in-polygon

and the results are absolutely identical:

the point [ 55.830902099609375, 49.066734313964844 ] is including in the first polygon but doesn't in the second.

But the point have to be included in two polygons and this is the issue.

Is there some mistake in the implementations of the libs or I don't know something?

Comment: Have you verified that the point is in fact inside both?

Comment: I checked it with google maps api and there is an example https://jsfiddle.net/7dv3xfuL/1/
It turned out the issue was about the "wrong" value of longtitude with a negative value(in my case -172.369491577).
If take a look on how google map drew the polygon we can see that the polygon is convex. And to build a convex polygon on the sets we have to convert the value -172... to postive one.

Comment: The thing is, first of all, the sets of the points are the geo coordinates and secondly, the sets describe the coordinates that cross the 180th meridian. so I got the negative value. To get the correct polygon I have to convert the angles of coordinates to the flat coordiantes, so to speak.